# Cannon connect to certain port for socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

For previous applications I used html5 websockets on client size to connect to local desktop app to get data from app and display on the client side (html + js), and it worked. Now I am trying to create similar project in nodejs + expressjs with full client side done with jade templates. I am unsuccessfully trying to connect with socket.io-client to my local desktop app:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('ws://127.0.0.1:12345');
socket.on('connect', function () { console.log('connected'); });
socket.on('event', function (data) { console.log('data'); });
socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log('disconnected'); });
```

1) Is it possible to fully recreate html5 websocket functionality with socket.io-client?

2) My local desktop app is waiting for the message before it transmits data. In html5 websockets I used:

```
 var registration="my registartion string";
 socket.send(registration);
```

What should I use to recreate this functionality socket.io-client?

Thank you

Comment: `socket.io` is not a websocket library (although it can _use_ websockets as a transport). If you need to use pure websockets, take a look at [`ws`](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

Comment: @robertklep, thank you. Ws did help.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io is wrong library. As @robertklep suggested Ws is the library to use to reproduce html5 socket functionality.